# Android запуск фоновых процессов, Worker

Tags: java, android

У меня такой вопрос, в приложении нужно реализовать работу фоновых процессов по периодическому определению координат пользователей.

Для этого решил использовать Worker

Задачи запускаются следующим образом

```
public boolean onCreate() {

    PeriodicWorkRequest myWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(GeomobyWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(myWorkRequest);

    return true;
}
```

Т.е. периодически, раз в 15 минут.

В самом Worker

```
    public Result doWork() {
// тут некоторая логика

// потом вызываю BroadcastReceiver

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(GeoGPSManager.NEW_INIT_LOCATION);
        filter.addAction(GeoGPSManager.NEW_CURRENT_LOCATION);
        filter.addAction(GeoBeaconManager.NEW_BEACON_UPDATE);
        filter.addAction(NEW_INSTANCE_ID);
        filter.addAction(UPDATE_FENCES);

        mCtx.registerReceiver(geoServiceReceiver, filter);
        mCtx.sendBroadcast(intent);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mCtx.getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

        return Result.success();    

}
```

В принципе все работает, вот только мне нужно чтобы процесс запускался после перегрузки, но в Android 8 я получаю следующую ошибку:

> 2019-10-03 11:28:02.108 1301-1488/? W/PackageManager: Unknown
>   permission android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION in package
>   com.geomoby.demoapp 2019-10-03 11:28:02.108 1301-1488/?
>   W/PackageManager: Not granting permission
>   android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to package
>   com.geomoby.demoapp because it was previously installed without
>   2019-10-03 11:28:02.108 1301-1488/? W/PackageManager: Not granting
>   permission android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE to package
>   com.geomoby.demoapp because it was previously installed without
>   2019-10-03 11:28:02.108 1301-1488/? W/PackageManager: Unknown
>   permission android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE in package
>   com.geomoby.demoapp 2019-10-03 11:28:02.108 1301-1488/?
>   W/PackageManager: Not granting permission
>   android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION to package
>   com.geomoby.demoapp because it was previously installed without

В Android 9 менее информативный лог

```
Background execution not allowed receiving intent BOOT_COMPLETED
```

В файле манифеста

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERMISSION_GRANTED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы запрашиваете пермишены в риал тайме? С 8 андроида пермишены необходимо запрашивать непосредственно при использовании приложения! Какая у Вас compileSdkVersion и targetSdkVersion?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 29 и targetSdkVersion 29

Comment: а пермишены запрашиваю в реалтайме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Андроид Q ввели еще один перемешен на получение локации в бэкграунде. Добавьте в манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Проверка есть ли у Вас уже такой пермишен (из фрагмента)

```
fun isBackgroundLocationPermissionGranted(): Boolean {
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) return true
    activity?.let {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(it, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    } ?: return false
}
```

запрос пермишена

```
fun requestsBackgroundLocationPermissionDialog() {
    requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION), REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION_PERMISSIONS)
}
```

ответ запроса вернется в

```
fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    presenter.checkPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}
```